# CoreNFC debug not working

Tags: ios, ios11, xcode9-beta

How programmatically work CoreNFC on xcode-9

```
func readerSession(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession, didInvalidateWithError error: Error) {
    //What I need to do here
}

func readerSession(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession, didDetectNDEFs messages: [NFCNDEFMessage]) {
    //What I need to do here
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let sessionReader = NFCNDEFReaderSession.init(delegate: self, queue: nil, invalidateAfterFirstRead: true)
    let nfcSession = NFCReaderSession.self

    let nfcTag = NFCTagCommandConfiguration.init()
    let tagType = NFCTagType(rawValue: 0)

    sessionReader.begin()

}
```

I want to know what I need to do for read some NFC tag.

Comment: In case you don't mind reading Objective-C code, here's a pre-made example project: https://github.com/x43x61x69/Core-NFC-Example

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are four steps to get it working:

1. Add the NFC Tag permission to your App Identifier in the Apple developer portal

[image]

2. Add a Code Signing Entitlement file to your project and build settings and add the following raw key and value:

[image]
[image]

3. Add the usage description to your Info.plist:

[image]

4. Implement the delegate and pass it to the `NFCNDEFReaderSession` init like this:

   ```
   import UIKit
   import CoreNFC

   @UIApplicationMain
   class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, NFCNDEFReaderSessionDelegate {

       var window: UIWindow?
       var session: NFCNDEFReaderSession?

       func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
           session = NFCNDEFReaderSession(delegate: self, queue: nil, invalidateAfterFirstRead: false)
           self.session?.begin()
           return true
       }

       func readerSession(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession, didInvalidateWithError error: Error) {
           print(error)
       }

       func readerSession(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession, didDetectNDEFs messages: [NFCNDEFMessage]) {
           print(messages)
       }

   }
   ```

Comment: is step 1 required?