# NFC readerSession never called

Tags: ios, swift, nfc, core-nfc

I have iPhone7 and iPhone8 (iOS12). 
I want to read NFC tag of iPhone7 from iPhone8. So I follow to this instruction
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44392379/10291727

The problem is that devices don't see each other and # readerSession # delegate is never called.

Please help me to fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

You can only read NDEF formatted tags with CoreNFC. You cannot "write" data; Your iPhone 7 doesn't have a NFC tag for the iPhone 8 to read.

It is not possible to use NFC for communication between two iOS devices

Comment: Paulw11 thanks, but iPhone 7 also contains NFC tag, right? Which format is it? And is it possible somehow to pass info between iPhones by NFC?

Comment: No, it doesn’t contain an NFC tag. It has an NFC chipset that can be used to read NDEF tags and which ApplePay uses to interact with payment terminals.  You can communicate between iOS devices using TCP/IP over WiFi or by using Bluetooth Low Energy